# Browser Tab Close Event for Javascript or ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events

How do I capture the browsers `Tab Close`-event in **JavaScript** or **EXTJS**. I have tried the following:

```
<script>
    window.onunload = (function(){
        return 'stay page ......';
    });
</script>
```

as well as

```
<script>
   window.onbeforeunload = (function(){
      return 'stay page ......';
   });
</script>
```

but this `onunload` is not working and `onbeforeunload` is working for `page refresh` and `page close` events. Please help me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried this?

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'beforeunload', function() {
alert('cross-exit tab click AND cross-exit browser click');
});

Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'unload', function() {
alert('cross-exit tab click');
});
```